# How do you get the host address and port from a System.Net.EndPoint?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, ip-address

I'm using a `TcpClient` passed to me from a `TcpListener`, and for the life of me I can't figure out a simple way to get the address and port it's connected to.

The best I have so far is `_client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();` which returns a string in the form `FFFF::FFFF:FFFF:FFF:FFFF%00:0000`. I've managed to extract the address and port using Regular Expressions, but this seems like overkill. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the `EndPoint` to an [IPEndPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.aspx)

```
var ep = _client.Client.RemoveEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
if (ep != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", ep.Address);
    Console.WriteLine("Port: {0}", ep.Port);
}
```

You shouldn't really need the test for != null, cause you know that it'll always be IPEndPoint if you're connecting to an internet address...